# Is the java source code generated from "wsimport <wsdl_url>" is actual soap web service code?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl url http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

now if i generate a java source code by

```
wsimport -keep http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL
```

Is it going to generate actual soap web service code or just a interface which can call web service ?

I have seen some videos on youtube and as far as i think it cannot generate the actual java source code of soap web service. Please correct me if i am wrong.

so suppose if i want to make changes in soap web service(written in java), the changes in the generated file will not serve the purpose.

May be my question seems very basic to you, but i was looking at an application code and got this confusion , so please answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

> The wsimport tool is used to parse an existing Web Services
>   Description Language (WSDL) file and generate required files (JAX-WS
>   portable artifacts) for **web service client** to access the published web
>   services.

wsimport generates and compile the web service artifacts needed to connect to the service. This utility does not generate the actual web service.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question , but for the record if you want to generate the actual WebService from an existing WSDL file you should use wsimport sibling which called [wsgen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html)